# Getting tile cache creation status on ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, tiles, rendering

I am creating a server side tile cache on ArcGIS Server 10.6.1 using
[ManageMapServerCacheTiles_server](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/server-toolbox/manage-map-server-cache-tiles.htm) with the `wait` option as the Python/ArcPy example suggests. Unfortunately this process takes 10+hrs.

I am interested in getting the tile cache status during the creation. Is the `status.gdb` file updated automatically during the rendering process and can I read it during the ongoing thread or is it locked?

Or is it better to send a request to the server side with proper credentials using the approach described in the article ["View cache completion status"](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/10.6/publish-services/windows/viewing-cache-completion-status.htm)?